# IsRequired in WCF

Tags: asp.net, wcf

If am adding a Data member it will be sent over the wire to the Client.  What is the advantage of adding Isrequired  ? Please Explain

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that the datamember you apply it to must be present when you pass a copy of the object across on the wire.

So,

```
[DataContract]

    public class MyObject
    {
    [DataMember] 
    public int numberTest;
    [DataMember(IsRequired=true)]
    public int numberMustBeThere;
    }
```

If you sent for the above:

```
<MyObject>
<numberTest>123</numberTest>
</MyObject>
```

it would fail as it states numberMustBeThere should exist

However, if you send either of these two, it would be fine, as default is false (so numberTest would not be required)

```
<MyObject>
<numberMustBeThere>123</numberMustBeThere>
</MyObject>

<MyObject>
<numberTest>123</numberTest>
<numberMustBeThere>123</numberMustBeThere>
</MyObject>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Ok it fails. When Client hits for the request it fails or server side ?

Comment: when the message arrives and is getting deserialized.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, when you state that the DataMember IsRequired, you are saying that an exception should be raised on the client in case the datacontract's field was not set. This is useful to specify mandatory fields in your data contract.

I hope it helps.

Regards,
Rodrigo